# How to use SQL Server database login cridentials as user login in laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

My client has a large **SQL Server** database which stores various forms of data for 20 companies. And each of these companies have access to respective sections of the database, by using their database login cridentials.

> To make things clear, i do not have a user table. But instead, each
>   user is actually a **database user**.

Right now, i am using a **custom MVC** of my own, and it is working very well. Like so :

```
$user = $_POST['login']
$pass = Hash::create('sha256', $_POST['password'], HASH_PASSWORD_KEY);

        try {
            $conn = new PDO(DB_TYPE . ':server=' . DB_HOST . ',1433 ;Database=' . DB_NAME, $user,  $pass);
            $baglantiDurumu = "baglandi";
        }
```

As this project is growing bigger, i thought it is time to switch to **Laravel**, so that i can benefit from the functionalities of it. But i have no idea how to achieve this in Laravel.

I will need this user/password to use in the connection string (database.php) eg:

```
    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'TestDb-3'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', $user),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', $pass),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

I assume, this alone is not enough to solve my problem, because in order to use Laravel's other functionalities such as `"Auth"`, `"Session"` and all the other classes related with user login, i need a user database. Which unfortunately i don't have.

> By the way, forgot to mention that all the users including me have only read privillage. No **INSERT**, no **UPDATE**, just **SELECT**.

Do you have any suggestions, or should i go back to my old MVC?

Comment: To be clear and update my answer if needed, do you want to connect to DB and login user with the same info in the same request?
If so, every DB has a one user deal with it?

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 Thanks for the answer, i will try and see what i can do. And for the question you asked, yes every login is actually a DB connection. We do not store the connection string. When a user is trying to login into system, he/she is actually giving us the connection string. But there are no several databases. One database with 20 users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**config/database.php**

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'TestDb-3'),
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

**AnyController.php**

```
public function anyThing(Request $request)
{
    config('database.sqlsrv.username', $request->input('db_username'));
    config('database.sqlsrv.password', bcrypt($request->input('db_password'));

    // Query Builder
    $data = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('table_name')->get();

    // Or Eloquent
    $data = TableModel::connection('sqlsrv')->get();

    return view('path.to.view')->with(compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You took your time and answered, and it's been a year since your answer. But i decided not to use laravel. Please accept my apologies for answering too late.